# C++ Improved efficiency to check if a BST is height balanced?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a function `isOk(Node*, int&)` that checks if the following property is respected for every node of the BST:

-The height of its left and right subtrees can differ by max 1 level.

One example could be:

[image: example]

This is the function I wrote:

```
    bool isOk(Node* tree, int& maxH)
    {
        //if leaf, property is respected
        if(!tree->left_ && !tree->right_) return true;
        
        //otherwise
        int hL = 0;
        int hR = 0;
        bool propL = isOk(tree->left_, hL);
        bool propR = isOk(tree->right_, hR);
        
        if(propL) hL++;
        if(propR) hR++;
        if(hL - hR => -1 && hL - hR <= 1) {
                maxH = max(hL, hR);
                return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

We assume that a struct Node is something like this:

```
struct Node
{
    Node* left_;
    Node* right_;
    int label_;

    //no constructor or destructor, this is not the focus
};
```

Initially I wrote this part:

```
/*...*/
    int hL = 0;
    int hR = 0;
    bool propL = isOk(tree->left_, hL);
    bool propR = isOk(tree->right_, hR);
    
    if(propL) hL++;
    if(propR) hR++;
/*...*/
```

in the following way:

```
int hL = height(tree->left_);
int hR = height(tree->right_);
bool propL = isOk(tree->left_, hL);
bool propR = isOk(tree->right_, hR);
```

where the function `height(Node*)` is:

```
int height( Node* tree)
{
    if(tree== NULL) return 0;
    int leftH = 0;
    int rightH = 0;
    leftH = height(tree->left_);
    rightH = height(tree->right_);
    return 1 + max(leftH, rightH);
}
```

Now, the complexity of `height` should be O(n) if I am not wrong. So, if use it inside my `isOk` function, its overall complexity should increase greatly, right?

That said, I tried to trace the height of each subtrees incremeting each time `hL` and `hR` on each call of `isOk`.

Is this something wrong I did?
Please correct me wherever I am wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about performance complexity or correct functionality? If the latter (functionality), why do you think something is wrong? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I am asking both actually. I can't really figure out if my function would work in both ways. That said, I am trying to understand IF I just did an optimization removing 'height(Node*)' function or not.

Comment: One question per question please, and you probably should make sure the algorithm is correct before worrying about its complexity. Keep in mind that this site exists to provide answers to future readers. (Getting an answer to your own question is secondary.) Things get rather confusing when the answers to two distinct questions exist on the same page.

Comment: Ok, then my main question is about optimization, I am sorry for making things confusiong!

Comment: Have you searched the internet for "c++ balanced binary tree"?  There are existing algorithms and examples of balanced binary trees.  Also research red/black trees.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was worrying about the complexity of the algotimth without implemeting the 'height' function inside the recursion. If this was already solved somewhere else in the internet I'm really sorry I did not found it!

Comment: Balanced binary trees are usually taught in data structures courses at universities.  Some good data structures books may discuss them as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have `isOk` return a `pair<bool, int>` where the `bool` represents whether the the node which is returning this value follows the said property or not and `int` represents it's height int the tree.

Suppose `pair<boor, int> propL, propR` are the values returned by the left and right children of the current node respectively, then the current node will satisfy the said property iff `propL->first == true && propR->first == true && (int)abs(propL->second-propR->second) <= 1`. Then this value along with the current node's height (which equals `max(propL->second, propR->second) + 1`) will be returned to the current node's parent.

Comment: I am sorry, but I kind new in programming and didn't ever use pair<> . I will try to read some documentation on it. Thanks